# Visual Studio 2022 create a custom tool for a file in a solution

Tags: visual-studio

I folks,

I have a VS2022 solution project containing a number of projects.  From time-to-time I need to run a custom script (cmd file) that generates some code.

I would like to use the 'run custom tool' option when right clicking on the file in the solution folder.

The only real constraint is that I need to use the visual Studio command prompt rather than the default command shell as this has the developer environment set up (paths to tools etc.).

I have an *Tools.External-Tools* option set up to open a visual studio command prompt at the appropriate location - however, this applies to all instances of VS, and I just require it being the one solution.

Does anyone have an example of doing this?

**Edit:**  Just in case it was not clear, I am looking at using the Custom Tool property that is visible in the properties window when a file is selected (executed by the run-custom-tool command in the context menu for the file).